# JPA criteria API, inject NULL value in multiselect

Tags: hibernate, jpa, select, null, criteria

How to do something like that :

`criteria.select( builder.construct( Person.class, idPath, NULL, name ) );`

Where NULL is supposed to be the email of the Person class.

It look quite weird but i really want to hide this field to prevent from future bugs that show the email in view when it shouldn't.

For now i've a service that call the standart select and set NULL manually to the email's field.
But it do not look efficient to reiterate over all returned entities.

Was thinking : if Hibernate/JPA can create Person class and setting good field at the right place, can't it just set NULL where i want and fix my problem faster than my service ?

Thx for your attention.

Comment: Use `dto` with the required fields to hide those that should be hidden

Comment: TY, so the only way to hide data with DTO is to create another class ?
I'll go for implement it, but i'm still looking for a JPA alternative if possible, still look faster, i really want to avoid reiterate over all returned entities

Comment: EDIT : TY, it was exactly what i was looking for, just need to find how to hide it from other dao access, with OneToMany relations.
Ty again